# Mysql - Check if String A contain String B or Substring B

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

Is there any other way to perform this far from `LIKE` and `REGEX` , I am trying to check if string `A` contain string `B` or a little part of string `B` like example below

`string A = "United State of America"
string B = "America"`

String `B` should be checked if it exist in String `A`

Currently i have used REGEXP and LIKE but sometimes it give me false output, please check mycodes below and give any suggestion.

```
//Using REGEXP
$first_five = substr($data[0], -7, 7);
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 'football' WHERE 'TEAMS' REGEXP '$first_five'");
//Using LIKE
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 'football' WHERE 'TEAMS' LIKE '%$first_five%'");`
```

Any idea which query can perform same job like my above querys??????

Comment: In which cases does it give false output? Please show the exact inputs and what happens

Comment: I am not that good with mysql but as far as i know if i execute the query the output to display must contain the criteria in my query, so for example if i execute the above query whether with REGEXP or LIKE method the output must contain what i have describe in my condition but you will find output that come they don't even contain what i have described in my condition, Hope you got my point. @SamiKuhmonen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mysql> SELECT INSTR('foobarbar', 'bar');
+---------------------------+
| INSTR('foobarbar', 'bar') |
+---------------------------+
|                         4 |
+---------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> SELECT INSTR('xbar', 'foobar');
+-------------------------+
| INSTR('xbar', 'foobar') |
+-------------------------+
|                       0 |
+-------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

**First of all:** Notice about deprecation warning:

> `mysql_query` **Warning** This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

**In second place:**
You should to [escape](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) parameters (be careful, also deprecated)

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM football WHERE TEAMS LIKE '%" . 
        mysql_real_escape_string($first_five) . 
        "%'";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
```